# App or tool for auto-crop receipt-like pictures?

Tags: image-processing, crop

I've bunch of scan of [receipts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receipt), the one that are printed on [thermal paper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_paper) which you get from any supermarkets and these were taken on the dark background. I'd like to auto-crop them in batch via some tool, to not include the background.

I'm looking for app or tool for batch auto-crop of receipt-like pictures taken either for iOSX or OSX.

Comment: Related: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/30948/best-way-to-flatten-a-curled-photographed-book-photograph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On OSX/Linux you can try with [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) command-line tools (e.g. [Trimming 'Noisy' Images -- Scanned Images](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#trim_noisy)).

Alternatively you can try [Scan Tailor](http://scantailor.org/) ([at GitHub](https://github.com/scantailor/scantailor)), an interactive post-processing tool for scanned pages (installation via [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/): brew install scantailor). Convert the images either from ScanTailor's GUI interface or from the command-line (Run: `scantailor --help` for help).

Check similar Q&A for Windows/Linux: [Auto-crop black margins dynamically of scanned images?](https://superuser.com/questions/613670/auto-crop-black-margins-dynamically-of-scanned-images)

For iOSX app (also available for OSX), you can try [Evernote](https://evernote.com/), so you can take a picture of documents or business cards (including [OCR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition)), and the app can auto-crop it (based on the content).

Other apps include: [Receipt Bank](http://www.receipt-bank.com/), [Expentory](https://expentory.com/), [Xpenditure](http://www.xpenditure.com/), [Kagazz](http://www.kagazz.com/).